# How to decrypt SHA-256 encrypted String with Secret key String?

Tags: java

This is my java code that encrypt the String values using the secret key and its properly work but i don't know how to decrypt that ecrypted values into My original values..?

```
        package com.password;

        import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
        import java.security.Key;
        import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
        import java.security.SignatureException;
        import java.util.Formatter;
        import javax.crypto.Mac;
        import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

        public class Sha256 {

     //Main Method that have the String values and key 
            public static void main(String s[]) {
                try {

                    String str ="HelloWorld"; //String Values
                    String key = "test@12345"; //Secret Key

                    String encry = hashMac(str, key);
//call the hashMac Method that encrypt the String using key and return the encrypted values....
                    System.out.println("Encryption : " + encry);
                } catch (SignatureException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    //hashMac Method that encrypt the data and convert into hex values...    
            public static String hashMac(String text, String secretKey)
                    throws SignatureException {

                try {
                    Key sk = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getBytes(), HASH_ALGORITHM);
                    Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(sk.getAlgorithm());
                    mac.init(sk);
                    final byte[] hmac = mac.doFinal(text.getBytes());
                    return toHexString(hmac);//call toHexString Methods....
                } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {
                    // throw an exception or pick a different encryption method
                    throw new SignatureException(
                            "error building signature, no such algorithm in device "
                                    + HASH_ALGORITHM);
                } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
                    throw new SignatureException(
                            "error building signature, invalid key " + HASH_ALGORITHM);
                }
            }

            private static final String HASH_ALGORITHM = "HmacSHA256";
    //toHexString Method...
            public static String toHexString(byte[] bytes) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bytes.length * 2);

                Formatter formatter = new Formatter(sb);
                for (byte b : bytes) {
                    formatter.format("%02x", b);
                }

                return sb.toString();

            }
        }
```

How to decrypt the Encrypted String....?

Comment: SHA is a _S_ ecure _H_ ash _A_ lgorithm. Hashing is irreversible. You cannot get the original text from a hash code. Btw, this is called _hashing_, not _encryption_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is my java code that encrypt the String values using the secret key

No it isn't. This is your Java code that creates a *message authentication code* using a *secure hash* of the string value, using the SHA-256 secure hash algorithm.

> and its properly work but i don't know how to decrypt that ecrypted values into My original values..?

There are no encrypted values here.

> How to decrypt the Encrypted String....?

There is no encrypted `String` here. There is a secure hash of a `String`, and the major property of secure hashing is that it is not reversible.

Your question doesn't make sense.

Possibly what you are looking for is a way to check the HMAC? In which case you need to recreate the HMAC from the same message with the same key, and compare.

Comment: ,Encrypted Values : 2bd9fe68764035e7758813695abbe1beb7a62abce6b9cc8a81a610e89ad6242f this is the encrypted values.

Comment: @user3911776 For the third or fourth time, those are *not* encrypted values. That is the value of the HMAC. It is not an encryption process and it is not reversible. Why you are posting the value and what you expect me to do about it are further mysteries.

Comment: what a d!ck is this @user3911776